# Architecture decisions for system comprising mobile app with database in cloud and varying user restriction levels

Tags: azure, database-design

I am looking to develop an app that is to be used by a fairly small number of people and which has to store and recall data from a cloud database. Users should have various access levels in that some can create stuff, some just read, others modify, some can do anything etc. Just like you would do on a file system.

I am currently considering Azure (very new to it) and thinking what would be the components involved in the project. Obviously, a mobile app (Xamarin.Forms) would be front end. Some kind of Cosmos DB or another database in the cloud. Blob storage too for the media files created by users. But my main question is how to implement the control of what user can do what actions to which data.

A simple way would be to do it within the app itself, but that is counter intuitive and a security risk. Even though this is internal app used by people in the same or sister organizations, it really sounds bad.

Best option would be if that's handled by database itself, but I am not aware of existence of such mechanism. Hopefully, this actually exists and someone will point me in the right direction.

Only other way I see is having some kind of mid layer, still on the back end but just before database. However that also seems clunky and am also unaware of how to even implement it "in cloud".

What would be my actual options?

To clarify, it's about having permissions assigned based on certain columns of a table, for example, and not about having different tables with different user that share parts of data.

That's why it is "*Architecture decisions*" question, and not "how do i give read permissions to user X of my database Y".

An answer might be "Database X" has what you want. Or, least favourably, "There's no way to offload that to DB. You will have to keep all data separately, so that users can only operate on their set of data, and then collate stuff on the backend". Or something in between, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not knowledgeable with Azure or any of that other stuff, but every DBMS will have user accounts that enable different permissions, eg for [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/cdevcsecure865880.html), [MySQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to/modify-user-privileges/), etc.

I would never implement authentication on the client side.